# Failed to create dynamic vector tiles using PostGIS on existing table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, vector-tiles

I am unable to run PostGIS `ST_AsMVTGeom`. I read [Serving Dynamic Vector Tiles from PostGIS](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/dynamic-vector-tiles-from-postgis) by Paul Ramsey and [the PostGIS documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVTGeom.html).

The code is below:

```
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*) FROM ( 
   SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(point_geom) AS geom
   FROM ancillary_data 
) mvtgeom
```

The error message:

```
ERROR:  function st_asmvtgeom(point) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(point_geom) AS geom
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8
```

Surprisingly the code below works.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_AsMVTGeom(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 5, 0 -5, 0 0))'),
ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096)),
4096, 0, false));
```

Edit:

I realized that I was using PostgreSQL point column instead of PostGIS geometry.But the problem is still unsolved.

I am using PostGIS 3.0.1 in PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: Look closely at the working example (or, let me link again, the [docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVTGeom.html)); the function signature requires at least a tile bounds parameter!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVTGeom.html) shows that ST_AsMVTGeom() requires at least two parameters.

The [article](https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/dynamic-vector-tiles-from-postgis) shows ST_AsMVTGeom() three times:

> So any query to generate MVT tiles will involve a call to ST_AsMVTGeom() to condition the data first, something like:
>
> ```
> SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(geom) AS geom, column1, column2
> FROM myTable
> ```
>
> […]
>
> So SQL calls that create tiles end up looking like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*) 
> FROM ( 
>   SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(geom) AS geom, column1, column2 
>   FROM myTable 
> ) mvtgeom
> ```
>
> […]
>
> With the bounds SQL we are now ready to calculate the full MVT-generating SQL statement in envelopeToSQL:
>
> ```
> WITH 
> bounds AS (
>     ...
> ), 
> mvtgeom AS ( 
>     SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.{geomColumn}, 3857), bounds.b2d) AS geom, 
>            {attrColumns}
>     ...
> ```

The first two code snippets are pseudocode (which is implied by the word "like" if you are paranoid enough), only the third one shows actual code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I missed out the lower part of the article. I think it was cut out of my browser or it was 3 am when I read it :). Let me read the article get back to you.